# What happens when you run out of attempts for a battle?

Tags: card-hunter

What happens when a player fails a mission enough times that they run out of attempts?

[image: Replay battle screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you fail, you will have 3 options:

1. Revive the Party for 15 gold.
2. Restart the Adventure.
3. Quit the Adventure.

[image]